# C++ Primer Lippman 5th exercise 2.27 b

Tags: c++

C++ Primer exercise 2.27  5th ed.
Exercise: Which of the following initializations are legal? Explain why.

(b) `int *const p2 = &i2;`

This is legal according to:
https://github.com/Mooophy/Cpp-Primer/tree/master/ch02#exercise-227

I don't see where `i2` has been declared?
(I've looked at the errata also.)

Comment: p2 is declared as a `const` pointer to an integer and is initialized with address of `i2`

Comment: Your reference shows a declaration of `i2` *after* the declaration of `p2`, but of course that doesn't help. Without seeing the exercise in the book (which I don't have) it's impossible to tell.

Comment: @Zakir: Yes, but we don't know what `i2` is (unless it's referring to a declaration that's shown *after* the declaration of `p2`). CORRECTION: `p2` is declared as a pointer to a `const` `int`; the pointer is not `const`. It's legal if `i2` is a `const int`, illegal if `i2` is a non-`const` `int`.

Answer (score 0):

It is exploiting the fact that the `*` goes with the name, not the type.

i2 is declared as an integer by the question above this one

```
int* ip, ip2;
```

not a pointer. So

```
 int *const p2 = &i2;
```

p2 is assigned the address of i2, a pointer. 
The const pointer of p2 does not come in to play unless you try and change the value of p2.